# multivariate derivatives in jax - efficiency question

Tags: python, jax

I have the following code which computes derivatives of the function:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp


def f(x):
    return jnp.prod(x)


df1 = jax.grad(f)
df2 = jax.jacobian(df1)
df3 = jax.jacobian(df2)
```

With this, all the partial derivatives are available, for example (with `vmap` additionally):

```py
x = jnp.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
               [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
               [11., 12., 13., 14., 15.],
               [16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
               [21., 22., 23., 24., 25.],
               [26., 27., 28., 29., 30.]])
df3_x0_x2_x4 = jax.vmap(df3)(x)[:, 0, 2, 4]
print(df3_x0_x2_x4)
# [  8.  63. 168. 323. 528. 783.]
```

The question is how can I compute `df3_x0_x2_x4` only, avoiding all the unnecessary derivative calculations (and leaving `f` with a single vector argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is how can I compute `df3_x0_x2_x4` only, avoiding all the unnecessary derivative calculations (and leaving f with a single vector argument)?

Essentially, you're asking for a way to compute sparse Hessians and Jacobians; JAX does not have general support for this (see previous issue threads; e.g https://github.com/google/jax/issues/1032).

*Edit*

In this particular case, though, since you're effectively computing the gradient/jaacobian with respect to a single element per derivative pass, you can do better by just applying the JVP to a single one-hot vector in each transformation. For example:

```py
def deriv(f, x, v):
  return jax.jvp(f, [x], [v])[1]

def one_hot(i):
  return jnp.zeros(x.shape[1]).at[i].set(1)

df_x0 = lambda x: deriv(f, x, one_hot(0))
df2_x0_x2 = lambda x: deriv(df_x0, x, one_hot(2))
df3_x0_x2_x4 = lambda x: deriv(df2_x0_x2, x, one_hot(4))
print(jax.vmap(df3_x0_x2_x4)(x))
# [  8.  63. 168. 323. 528. 783.]
```

---

*Previous answer*

If you're willing to relax your "leaving f with a single argument" criterion, you could do something like this:

```py
def f(*x):
  return jnp.prod(jnp.asarray(x))

df1 = jax.grad(f, argnums=4)
df2 = jax.jacobian(df1, argnums=2)
df3 = jax.jacobian(df2, argnums=0)

df3_x0_x2_x4 = jax.vmap(df3)(*(x.T))
print(df3_x0_x2_x4)
# [  8.  63. 168. 323. 528. 783.]
```

Here rather than computing all gradients and slicing out the result, you are only computing the gradients with respect to the specific three elements you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you! I tested also the following solution: `df1 = jax.grad(f); df2 = jax.grad(lambda x: df1(x)[0]); df3 = jax.grad(lambda x: df2(x)[2]); print(jax.vmap(df3)(x)[:, 4])`, but it seems the trick with `jax.jvp` does the job most efficiently.